# Smart trainer compatibility

Tags: training, trainer

I am about to purchase an Elite Turbo Muin Smart Trainer, will it work with [RGT Cycling](https://www.rgtcycling.com/) ?

Does it have all the necessary power data to be accurate?
If not, what smart trainers do work with RGT Cycling ?

Comment: Is it the direct drive or B+ trainer ? Both should be compatible with RGT but the direct drive trainer will be better as fully smart.

Comment: Post the exact model number

Answer (score 1):

It looks like there are a number of trainers that Elite sold under the Muin name, so be very sure you're getting one that's "smart." Also, that's not a current model—it was first introduced in 2014, which is a long time in the industry. Trainers communicate with apps according to a standard so compatibility generally isn't an issue, but if this is old enough, it might predate the standard. Looking at DC Rainmaker, the oldest review he has of an Elite trainer is [this 2016 review](https://www.dcrainmaker.com/2016/09/elite-drivo-trainer-in-depth-review.html) for a different model, and he writes that compatibility is good, which leads me to think it would be good for other models of similar vintage. Probably.

RGT does show that it is compatible with Elite trainers without specifying particular models. If you want to be absolutely certain, contact RGT to ask.